# ElasticSearch-Net NEST search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST lib, and very basic setup according to the document. I've added index, mapping, etc.

But when I try to do search it always gives me, "An item with the same key has already been added". It confused me alot on what the error means.

```
        var result = client.Search<Contact>(s => s
            .AllIndices()
            .From(0)
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q => q
                .MatchAll())
        );
```

Here is the Contact:

```
public class Contact
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this peace of code is causing error? Which version of ES, NEST do you sue?

Comment: May you share Contact class as well?

Comment: Rob, I'm using ES v1.5.2, NEST v1.5.0

Comment: Your example is working like a charm with NEST 1.5.0. May you share more details?

Comment: Rob, interesting that if I don't use any mapping it works fine, but after I put my custom mappings in it gives me that mysterious error, "An item with the same key has already been added".

Comment: So attach this custom mapping and we will see what is going on :)

Comment: Rob, it suddenly works, sorry for bothering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a contact in elastic with the same email address twice. You could change the Email property to a string array perhaps?